# Why won't Discord chatbot in JavaScript respond?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am working on this simple chatbot following the [discord tutorial](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).

The chatbot has logged in to my server... I type in the chat room on Discord 'ping,' but the chatbot does not respond "Pong" as it should.

Below is the main.js code:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
      console.log("we got a hello!")
    await interaction.reply('Pong!');
  }
});

client.login('token');
```

Note: I have a secret token where it has 'token'

In my Terminal it says `Logged in as Quote.it#4979!` and my bot is online when I view it in the server in Discord.

But nothing happens when in Discord I write in 'ping'. How can I better diagnose what is going on?

Comment: Interactions and messages are completely different things, interactions are the new features that discord added, either slash commands, user commands or message commands, while message events are the complete type in messages. To use interaction commands, you need to register them, while text commands will need the message content intent. You can refer to https://discord.com/developers/docs! Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of problems here, first, it doesn’t look like you are registering the ping command see [here](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html#guild-commands), and second, you don’t have the right intents, you need the GUILD_MESSAGES one see [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents).

Here’s a simple ping pong bot:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js')

const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
    partials: ['CHANNEL', 'MESSAGE'],
})

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('ping')) {
        message.channel.send('pong!')
    }
})

client.login('token')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that's super helpful

Comment: The bot will respond in the server. Do you know how to make it respond with 'pong' as a message back to the user who sent it? I originally thought the 'messageCreate' was for messages to the sender but it posts in the chat server instead... thanks

Comment: If you want to send a direct message you can use 
`message.author.send('Pong!')` instead of 
`message.channel.send('Pong')`

Comment: OK! great it works... thanks a ton

Comment: Is it possible to respond to DMs as a chatbot in Discord? Might you know of the function that listens to DMs? Thanks

Comment: If you add the `Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES` Intent they will show up with the messageCreate handler. You can then check if it’s a DM `if (message.guild === null) {}`
[example](https://gist.github.com/wylie39/87e34f807f88958fa8ad7d5f7480f0a7)

Comment: Thank you again -- you've been awesome at guiding me through this